# half signal strength from wireless rtl8188ce lubuntu

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, realtek-wireless, signal

I get super slow speeds (half the signal strength I get on windows) and an unstable connection. I ran  [this script](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12350385#post12350385) and this is the info I get on Lubuntu 19.04 Kernel 5.0.0-29-generic.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:9181]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
```

```
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500                                                 
    inet 192.168.1.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255                                   
    inet6 fe80::c57c:16fa:818a:5f04  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>                                    
    ether 74:e5:43:42:5a:96  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)                                                 
    RX packets 364657  bytes 513997124 (513.9 MB)                                                        
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0                                                          
    TX packets 181053  bytes 20326173 (20.3 MB)                                                          
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: What's your `MTU`?

Comment: MTU is explained here: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/change_the_mtu_of_a_network_interface.html

Comment: MTU is 1500, signal strenght is the real problem, i get 30-40% and windows give me 80-90% im less than 10m from the router